# Javascript Currency Mask on Plain Text

Tags: javascript, text, mask

I have this screen where I my user type a currency value on a Input element. When I save it on my Database, it goes like a text. Ie: 10000.

I am trying to show this value in another screen with a currency mask like $10.000 but I don´t want to use a input field. I am just showing the value inside a `<ul>` .

How do I do that with Javascript???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
.toLocaleString('pt-BR', { style: 'currency', currency: 'BRL' })
```

did the trick.